# Switching from ng-route to angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Since I needed nested views in my AngularJS application (1.4), I decided to switch routing library from ngRoute to ui.router.

Now everything seems to work fine but in some controller I still have to import ngRoute in order not to crash the application.
One of these contrller is the controller for the landing page:

```
angular.module(
    'myApp.landing', ['ngRoute'], ["$compileProvider", function($compileProvider){
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|sms|whatsapp):/);
}]).
```

Here if I switch from 'ngRoute' to 'ui.router' I get this error:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…Flocalhost%3A3003%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)
```

The problem is that the error does not really tell me much about what's going on and which part of my code still depend on the module ngRoute.

Do you have an idea about how to approach this problem?

Comment: One thing to try is using the non-minified version of angular. This should provide a more verbose error message.

Comment: Thanks it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: How did you include your ui router ?

Comment: The problem was that I left some .config("$routeProvider") in some controllers and that is a dependency of ngRoute. Deleted those the problem was solved!